# Warning: current() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

When I was verifying the operation with Symfony4, the following error appeared.
I want to get the staff who are logged in.
`current()` is not found in the code and the cause cannot be identified.
Do you have any ideas?
I changed from ChoiceList to ChoiceLoader, which may have an effect.

Error

```
Warning: current() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

at vendor/symfony/form/Extension/Core/DataTransformer/ChoiceToValueTransformer.php:32
  at Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataTransformer\ChoiceToValueTransformer->transform(object(Staff))
     (vendor/symfony/form/Form.php:1111)
  at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->normToView(object(Staff))
     (vendor/symfony/form/Form.php:350)
  at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->setData(object(Staff))
     (vendor/symfony/form/Extension/Core/DataMapper/PropertyPathMapper.php:49)
  at Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataMapper\PropertyPathMapper->mapDataToForms(object(Coordinate), object(RecursiveIteratorIterator))
     (vendor/symfony/form/Form.php:383)
  at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->setData(object(Coordinate))
     (vendor/symfony/form/Form.php:487)
  at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->initialize()
     (vendor/symfony/form/FormBuilder.php:217)
  at Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder->getForm()
     (vendor/symfony/form/FormFactory.php:30)
  at Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory->create('Ahi\\Sp\\AdminBundle\\Form\\Type\\Article\\CoordinateType', object(Coordinate), array('method' => 'POST', 'action' => '/admin/sp/shop/coordinate/3860', 'login_staff' => object(Staff)))
     (vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Controller/ControllerTrait.php:312)
  at Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller->createForm('Ahi\\Sp\\AdminBundle\\Form\\Type\\Article\\CoordinateType', object(Coordinate), array('method' => 'POST', 'action' => '/admin/sp/shop/coordinate/3860', 'login_staff' => object(Staff)))
     (src/Ahi/Sp/AdminBundle/Controller/BaseArticleController.php:288)
  at Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Controller\BaseArticleController->editAndUpdate(object(Request), 'coordinate', '3860')
     (src/Ahi/Sp/AdminBundle/Controller/Sp/Shop/ArticleController.php:113)
  at Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Controller\Sp\Shop\ArticleController->editAction(object(Request), 'coordinate', '3860')
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:149)
```

ArticleController.php

```php
    protected function editAndUpdate(Request $request, $articleType, $id)
    {
        if ($articleType == 'coordinate'){
            $form = $this->createForm(CoordinateType::class, $article, array(
                "method" => "POST",
                "action" => $this->generateUrl($this->updateRoute, array("articleType" => $articleType, "id" => $id)),
                //Error part
                "login_staff" => $this->getStaff(),
            ));
```

CoordinateType.php

```php
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $wearerChoiceList = new StaffChoiceLoader($this->staffService, $options['login_staff']);
        $builder->add("wearer", EntityType::class, array(
            "required" => false,
            "class" => "AhiSpCommonBundle:Staff",
            "choice_loader" => $wearerChoiceList,
        ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setRequired(array(
            "login_staff",
        ));
    }
```

StaffChoiceLoader.php

```php
class StaffChoiceLoader implements ChoiceLoaderInterface
{
    public function __construct($staffService, $loginStaff)
    {
        $this->staffService = $staffService;
        $this->loginStaff = $loginStaff;
    }
    public function setCurrentStaff($currentStaff)
    {
        $this->currentStaff = $currentStaff;
    }
    public function loadChoiceList($value = null)
    {
        // Get the same shop staff as the login staff
        $staffs = $this->staffService->getStaffByShop($this->loginStaff->getShop());

        // If the current staff is not included in the acquired staff (due to transfer etc.), add it to the end
        if ($this->currentStaff && !array_search($this->currentStaff, $staffs)) {
            $staffs[] = $this->currentStaff;
        }
        return new ChoiceList($staffs, $staffs);
    }
```

ArticleType.php

```php
        $staff = $options['login_staff'];
        if ($staff->getShop() && $staff->getShop()->getApprovalFlg()) {
            // For shops that use the approval function
            if ($staff->isManage()) {
                // Shop administrator (save draft, wait for approval, post immediately)
                $builder->add("draft", SubmitType::class);
                $builder->add("approvalRequest", SubmitType::class);
                $builder->add("publish", SubmitType::class);
            } else {
                // General staff (save draft, waiting for approval)
                $builder->add("draft", SubmitType::class);
                $builder->add("approvalRequest", SubmitType::class);
            }
        } else {
            // For shops that do not use the headquarters management screen or approval function (save draft, post)
            $builder->add("draft", SubmitType::class);
            $builder->add("publish", SubmitType::class);
        }
```

Comment: It seems so obvious, i must miss something here. Can't you just:
If getStaff returns null, pass an empty array instead, or get getStaff to return an empty array, instead of null.

Comment: @AgathoSAreS Thanks for your comment. If you let it go, something will go wrong with the function of login_staff. I tried passing an empty array, but I got the following error with ArticleType (added): ```Call to a member function getShop () on array```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by the following method.

```php
   /**
     *
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Route("/initialSetting")
     *
     * @Template("@AhiSpAdminBundle/Security/initialSetting.html.twig")
     */
    public function initialSettingAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->initialSettingAndUpdateAction($request);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @Method("PUT")
     * @Route("/initialSetting")
     *
     * @Template("@AhiSpAdminBundle/Security/initialSetting.html.twig")
     */
    public function updateAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->initialSettingAndUpdateAction($request);
    }

    public function initialSettingAndUpdateAction(Request $request)
    {
        $key = $request->query->get("key");
        $staff = $this->get("admin.staffService")->getStaffByUrlKey($key);

        if (!$staff || $staff->getPassword()) {
            throw new HttpException(
                400,
                 The specified stuff prowl initialization URL does not exist or has expired.
                "\n".
                "Ask the administrator to reissue the URL."
            );
        }

        $form = $this->createForm(InitialSettingType::class, $staff, array(
            "method" => "PUT",
            "action" => $this->generateUrl("ahi_sp_admin_security_update", array("key" => $key)),
        ));

        if ($request->isMethod('PUT')) {
            if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isSubmitted() && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {

                $this->get("admin.staffService")->clearUrlKey($staff);
                $this->get("admin.staffService")->save($staff);
                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Staff profile Initial settings have been completed.');

                $this->autoLogin($staff);
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('ahi_sp_admin_default_index'));
            } else {
                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'Staff profile Initial settings could not be completed. Please check the input contents.');
            }
        }

        return array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        );
    }
```